# groupby / agg. --> Sorting on one of several calculated columns

Tags: python, pandas

in the example below, I would like to sort by `'count'`, but I get `KeyError: 'count'`.
Dou you have any idea how to solve it?

---

Code

```
df[['a', 'b']].groupby(['a']).agg(
['count','mean','median','min','max','mad','std','var','sem','skew','quantile']).sort()
```

---

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the `KeyError` using `df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(20,2)), columns=list('ab'))`. Can you post an example which demonstrates the error?

Comment: Same - can't reproduce error. But you can use .agg([np.size,np.mean...])  instead. Here np is numpy

Comment: Thanks for trying to replicate. You can replicate the dataframe that I am using by generating the following: `df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(20,5)))` and then a query that would reproduce the same error would be: `df2.iloc[:, :2].groupby([1]).agg(
    ['count','mean','median','min','max','mad','std','var','sem','skew','quantile']).sort([1])` by tring to sort on the `column[1]`